# Android Is AccountManager add Browser Page Open

Tags: android, browser, passwords, accountmanager

Is AccountManager logic used for opening web pages in Browser? I mean if user opened gmail.com, entered his credentials, and selected remember password, I can see that these details are stored in Web View DB, However I could not figure out whether it is using AccountManager to create an a/c for this user or the user credentials are directly sent to the server using some url or xml format? Please let me know where this Browser sending user credentials to the server code is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccountManager details are never used in Browser to find out which user is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

it is useful

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
uri u = Uri.parse(websiteText.getText().toString());
i.setData(u);
try {
startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(PassEdit.this, R.string.invalid_website, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding username and password as extras to the above intent, but it didnt help. It shows Gmail Login Screen, which is asking for username and password again. And moreover I want to access this from Browser Framework code itself not from a separate app.